# Programmatically determining rendered NSString dimensions and offsets

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uifont

Framing this question as directly and with as much information as possible, so as to allow a definitive answer. There's even a picture!

I have a simple subclass of `UILabel` (subclassed to allow rendering of stroked text).

Header:

```
//  svCustomNumeralLabel.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface svCustomNumeralLabel : UILabel

@property UIFont *customFont;
@property CGPoint drawPoint;

@end
```

Complete implementation:

```
#import "svCustomNumeralLabel.h"

@implementation svCustomNumeralLabel

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}


-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)initialize{
    self.customFont =  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Forgotten Futurist" size:200.0];
    self.drawPoint = CGPointMake(-10.0,-39.0);

    float capHeight = self.customFont.capHeight;
    NSLog(@"Cap height: %f", capHeight);
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);//RGBA
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFillStroke);

    float descender = self.customFont.descender;
    float ascender = self.customFont.ascender;

    NSLog(@"Ascender: %f descender: %f", ascender, descender);

    CGSize frameSize = self.frame.size;
    NSLog(@"Frame width: %f height: %f", frameSize.width, frameSize.height);

    CGSize unDrawnSize = [self.text sizeWithFont:self.customFont];
    NSLog(@"Undrawn width: %f height: %f", unDrawnSize.width, unDrawnSize.height);

    CGSize drawnSize = [self.text drawAtPoint:self.drawPoint withFont:self.customFont];
    NSLog(@"Drawn width: %f height: %f", drawnSize.width, drawnSize.height);

}
```

I've put an instance of this class into a `UIView` in Interface Builder. The `svCustomNumeralLabel`'s view has been manually sized in IB to 80.0 width, 127.0 height.

I've set the value of `self.drawPoint` in the `initialize()` method by trial-and-error, to its current value of `(-10.0, -39.0)`.

The result, with these manually set and hard-wired values, is a nice numeral, exactly positioned within its container frame (which for clarity is set to have a gray background):[image: svCustomNumeralLabel screengrab]

The `NSLog` output from the run above:

```
Cap height: 126.600006
Ascender: 165.601562 descender: -58.400002
Frame width: 80.000000 height: 127.000000
Undrawn width: 100.000000 height: 229.000000
Drawn width: 99.200005 height: 229.000000
```

## My question

How could I have programmatically determined the value of self.drawPoint to achieve this result, ie the '0' character rendered at the exact top-left?

Secondary question: how can I compute a correct value for the precise width and height of the character, as actually rendered, to facilitate fitting it nice and snug in its view?

As you can see from the `NSLog` outputs, there appears to be very little information available that bears much resemblance to the actual numeral as drawn. The only metric that correlates with frame dimensions is `UIFont.capHeight`. There appears to be no information that I could reliably use to determine the `(-10.0, -39.0)` offset value of `self.drawPoint`.

Answer (score 0):

The AppKit provides some nice additions to the Foundation Framework's `NSString`: [NSString UIKit Additions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html)

Of particular interest: `- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font` and related methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn all about a font at the CGFont level:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGFont/Reference/reference.html

At an even deeper level, you can use Core Text:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Operations/Operations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533-CH4-SW20

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Looks like `CGFontGetGlyphBBoxes` might be worth a look.